# Gson, creating a simple JsonArray of JsonObjects

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to build a JsonArray of JsonObjects using gson.
Each JsonObject will take the following format,

```
{"image":"name1"}
{"image":"name2"}
```

and so on.

I have a string array of the names ("name1","name2",...)
I cannot convert string array directly in to a JsonArray. I'm trying to create JsonObjects iteratively and add it to a JsonArray.

```
        JsonObject innerObject;
        JsonArray jArray = new JsonArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<names.length; i++)
        {
            innerObject = new JsonObject();
            innerObject.addProperty("image",names[i]);
            jArray.add(innerObject);
        }
```

But as I understand, `add` method in JsonArray takes a JsonElement and here I'm giving a JsonObject. I couldn't find a way to convert JsonObject to JsonElement. 
The whole point of using gson will be gone when I do this. Is there a better way?

Comment: `JsonObject` extends `JsonElement`, so there's no reason you can't add one to a `JsonArray` using the `add(JsonElement)` method.  No conversion is required.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are going to use GSON use it like this to convert to object

```
List<Image>images = new Gson().fromJson(json, Image[].class);
```

To get json string

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(images);
```

That's the point of gson you should not manipulate the data with loops and stuff. You need to take advantage of its powerful model parsing.

Answer (score 6):

First, create a class that represents a single json object, e.g.:

```
class MyObject {
    private String image;

    public MyObject(String name) { image = name; }
}
```

Gson will use the class' variable names to determine what property names to use.

Then create an array or list of these using the data you have available, e.g.

```
ArrayList<MyObject> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
allItems.add(new MyObject("name1"));
allItems.add(new MyObject("name2"));
allItems.add(new MyObject("name3"));
```

Finally, to serialize to Json, do:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(allItems);
```

And to get the data back from `json` to an array:

```
MyObject[] items = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyObject[].class);
```

For simple (de)serialization, there is no need to be dealing directly with Json classes.

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Awesome! Your example code helped me a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe too late but... There is a way to do without creating a new class if you dont need it:

```
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonArray
...
...
JsonArray jobj = new JsonArray();
String[] names = new String[]{"name1","name2","name3"};
for(String name : names) {
   JsonObject item = new JsonObject();
   item.addProperty("name",name);
   jobj.add(item);
}
System.out.println(jobj.toString());// ;)
```